# A Linear Operator of Rank 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator with rank $1$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.Then Which of the following are true?

1)either $T$ is diagonalizable or  $T$ is nilpotent.

2)$T$ is both diagonalizable and  nilpotent.

> I take $T$ as constant mapping and got it as diagonalizable. So can we say that 1) is true and 2) is false? Is there any other method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) if $T$ is rank one, then $T=uv^T$ with nonzero $u,v$. If $v^Tu=0$ then $T$ is nilpotent. Otherwise $T$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $v^Tu$ (for eigenvector $u$) and eigenvalue $0$ (eigenvectors are all vectors orthogonal to $v$).

2) is definitely false as a diagonalizable and nilpotent mapping must be zero.

Comment: How could u say that if $T$ is rank one, then $T=uv^T$ ?Plz Explain....

Comment: rank one means that the columns space has dimension one, hence all columns are multiples of one fixed column. Call that column $u$, put the factors into $v$, then $T = uv^T$

Answer (score 5):

We have $\dim\ker T=\dim V-1=n-1$ since the rank of $T$ is $1$ hence $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $n-1$ and then there are two possibilities:

- If $\operatorname{tr}(T)\ne 0$ then the last eigenvalue is $\lambda=\operatorname{tr}(T)$ and $T$ is diagonalizable since
  $$V=\ker T\oplus E_\lambda(T)$$
- $\operatorname{tr}(T)= 0$ then $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ so it's nilpotent and not diagonalizable since $T\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

if $A$ is rank one, then $A = uv^\top$ for some $u, v \neq 0.$ the eigenvalues are $v^\top u, 0, 0, \cdots, 0$ and the corresponding  eigenvctors are $u$ and a basis of $v^\perp.$  since $range$ and kernel of $A$ fill up the space if $u$ and $v$ are not orthogonal, $A$ is diagonalizable.

in the case where $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, you have a nilpotent nondiagonalisable rank one matrix. for example, $u = \pmatrix{1\\0}, v = \pmatrix{0\\1}, uv^\top=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.$

Comment: This is just wrong. A Jordan block of size $2$ for $\lambda=0$ is rank one and nilpotent, but not zero.

Comment: @daw, true. can't believe i forgot that.